# How to run business logic in ASYNC parallel in queue list? i have sync process want to convert to aync process in queue

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

now i have sync process which is work fine (code below). But not good one it takes longtime and block the process.

```
//1.fetch userId from DB about 5000 Ids
var ids = fetchIds();

foreach( int id in ids){

    doBusinessLogicAndSendEmailReport(id);

}
```

I want to do like. I want to make it in async.

1.queue 5000 id to ListQueue and

2. compute limit 50 in parallel
3. then if one is  completed then grab the new one (dequeue) from the ListQueue and do until all ListQueue gone.

How to do this in  ASYNC PARALLE?
I did some search I found related topic (i dont know which to use)

Job
Task
Task Scheduler
PTL

Which one is best for this scenario?
Any pattern or best practice.

Comment: TPL and TAP patterns are best suited for that. take a look at this blog by stephen clearly. which i learned a lot
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/async-producer-consumer-queue-2-more.html

Comment: I had read it. I have to start learn Task then come back and read again. Thank you

Comment: also dont forget semaphores.